# free Image manipulation tool in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

Is there any free(source code) image manipulation tool available?. The functionality should contain Free Text, Drawing tools (Circle, Rectangle), Pencil , Line , Zoom in, Zoom out  and rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this post](http://nuigroup.com/forums/viewthread/6642/) from 2009 that mentions this site:

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/

> **AForge.Imaging**, which is the biggest library of the framework so far, contains different image processing routines, which are aimed to help as in image enhancement/processing, as in some computer vision tasks:

Though as it's for image processing it only really meets the

> Resize and rotation (nearest neighbor, bilinear, bicubic);

requirement from your list